# Select same number of rows even if data is not there

Tags: sql, select

I want to write a query to always select the same number of rows, even if the data is not there. If the data is not there, I would still like to select something in its place.

For example, if I want to select the amount in my bank account for the last 5 years, but I only have data for the last 3 years, could I still select 5 rows and just have 0's for the two missing years?

```
| Year | Balance |
| 2014 | $5      |
| 2013 | $10     |
| 2012 | $31     |
| 2011 | $0      | << Doesn't exist
| 2010 | $0      | << Doesn't exist
```

Is this possible? Thanks for any help.

Comment: "Is this possible?" Yes. "How to do it?" [Please read this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and then try to figure out how to do it. Hint: You need a table with all the years, and then use joins to get the output you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to solving this is using an outer join. It is tempting to think of your actual table of data as the "main" table, but what you really want is a table of all possible years. I didn't have a table of years, so I made one up on the fly:

`select 2010 as Year 
union select 2011 as Year 
union select 2012 as Year 
union select 2013 as Year 
union select 2014 as Year`

This gives me a list of all the years I care about.

Then I use an outer join to join it to my table with real data. The outer join will just return *NULL* values for the stuff that isn't there. But I don't want *NULL*s, I want zeroes, so I use the `isnull` function to make them zeros if they are null. And then I end up with this:

`select YearList.Year, isnull(Bals.Balance, 0) as theBalance 
from 
(select 2010 as Year 
union select 2011 as Year 
union select 2012 as Year 
union select 2013 as Year 
union select 2014 as Year) as YearList
left join (select Year, Balance from Balances) as Bals
on YearList.Year = Bals.Year`

Answer (score 1):

Using mssql, this will work. There are other similar functions for other DBs.

`SELECT TOP 5 year, ISNULL(balance,0) FROM yourtable`